# Switch Browser Command in Robot Framework isn't working

Tags: selenium, robotframework

In my test case, I have to open two browsers and Switch to the first browser opened, but the Switch Browser isn't working for me, the command doesn't return any error but doesn't switch the browser.

I Already tried using the command using index and alias but nothing worked.

```
   Open browser                   ${url}                       ${browser}      1

   Open Browser    ${url}      Firefox

   Switch Browser      1
```

My code:

```
   *** Settings ***
   Library  SeleniumLibrary   

   *** Test Cases ***
Two Browsers
   Open browser                   ${url}                       ${browser}      1

   Do some actions...   
   Open Browser    ${url}      Firefox

   Do some actions...

   Switch Browser      1
```

When the command Switch Browser is executed nothing happened, doesn't change of browser.
I tried using the command `Press Keys      None        ALT+TAB`
but this doesn't work too.
When I Use the command `Get Window Identifiers` return information about only one browser.

Comment: Resolved:

I understood now, the switch is working but visually the switch doesn't happen, but in background it happens, I had added more commands after the switch and the commands are being executed in the correct browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can have aliases for diffrent browsers to navigate between them

```
*** Keywords ***

Open Browser Window with Alias 1
    Open Browser  about:blank   ${defaultBrowser}  alias=${window_alias_1}  remote_url=${env}

    maximize browser window

Open Browser Window with Alias 2
    Open Browser  about:blank   ${defaultBrowser}  alias=${window_alias_2}  remote_url=${env2}

    maximize browser window

Switch to Browser with Alias 1
    switch browser  ${window_alias_1}

Switch to Browser with Alias 2
    switch browser  ${window_alias_2}

*** Test Case ***
Test
   Open Browser Window with Alias 1
   # do your logic here for browser 1
   Open Browser Window with Alias 2
   # do your logic here for browser 2
   Switch to Browser with Alias 2
   #some more logic
   Switch to Browser with Alias 1
   ${log}   Finished
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch Browser actually works. If you try to switch browser to first window try to click an element/input text it will work but it will not change the view.

Example:

First Browser - Google

Second Browser - Bing

Switch browser 1 (Which is the first browser)

Input text to Search bar (Use any locator)